# Example for 2 disjoint languages that cannot be separated by a decidable language

Tags: computability

**Question:**
Let A, B be languages such that A ∩ B = ∅.
Say that a language C separates A and B if: A ⊆ C and B ⊆ $C^c$.
Describe two languages A, B ∈ RE, that cannot be separated by any C, such
that C ∈ R. 
R is the class of decidable languages and RE is that class of Recursively Enumerable languages.

**Thoughts:**
First I thought about taking language and it's complement- But I've read that both language and complement cannot reside at the same time in RE.
Second try: (on $\Sigma=${a,b,c})
(M is a TM)

A={$<M>$ | $L(M) \subseteq a^*$} (we've seen in class this is undecidable)

B={$<M>$ | $L(M) \subseteq b^*$}

C={$<M>$ | $L(M) \subseteq a^*c^*$}

So C is also in RE as I see it, But I'm afraid also that $C^c$ is also in RE which may destroy my idea. 
Is this a good direction? Other suggestions?

Comment: You probably mean $A \subset C$ and $B \subset C^c$. Otherwise you can always take $C =\Sigma^\ast$. Also: What are R and RE?

Comment: yes, I fixed that now (I forgot to put the compliment on C). R is the class of decidable languages and RE is that class of Recursively Enumerable languages.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Consider an [acceptable programming system](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Admissible_numbering) $\varphi_i$ for $i\in\mathbb N$.

1. Let $A=\{i\;|\;\varphi_i(i)=0\}$
2. Let $B=\{i\;|\;\varphi_i(i)=1\}$

$A$ and $B$ are RE.

Suppose there is a recursive set $C$ that separates $A$ and $B$. As $C$ is recursive, there is $c$ such that $\varphi_c(x)=1$ if $x\in C$ else $0$

Then $$\varphi_c(c)=1 \Rightarrow c\in B \Rightarrow c\notin C\Rightarrow \varphi_c(c)=0$$

$$\varphi_c(c)=0 \Rightarrow c\in A \Rightarrow c\in C\Rightarrow \varphi_c(c)=1$$

This is impossible : there is no such recursive set $C$.

Comment: Hi, thanks for the reply. We haven't studied the subject of acceptable programming systems. I also didn't understand how C is defined. Could you please elaborate?

Comment: We suppose that $C$ exists, and from that we prove a contradiction, so $C$ can't exist. If you didn't see what is   aps, did you at least see what is a universal machine that can simulate all other machines ?

Comment: yes we saw the Universal Machine.

Comment: How did you define it ? So I can use a definition you know.

Comment: Universal Turing Machines
Algorithm  (Universal TM U)
On input <M, w>, where <M> and w are binary strings separated by 111.
Checks that <M, w> is a proper encoding of a TM.
Emulate M(w) 
1. Accept, if M enters its accept state
2. Reject, if M enters its reject state

Comment: OK, so just replace $\varphi_x(y)$ by $U\langle x,y\rangle$ (with $U$ being the universal TM) in my explanations above and $0$ by reject and $1$ by accept.

Comment: So A is the set of all i's for which the Universal machine with input <i,i> rejects? From what we defined the first parameter to U should be a machine encoding and the second some string of input, what is $i$ here then?

Comment: you're right, $i$ is both program and data. This is the heart of computability : considering input data as machine encoding.

Comment: $\varphi_C$ is the "decider" of C? (if it were decidable)

Comment: Yes $\varphi_c$ is the decider of the recursive set (capital) $C$, and (small) $c$ is the string that encodes the machine $\varphi_c$. By definition, $C$ is a recursive set, so it is decidable.

Comment: Got it, thanks!!!